# How to chain promise in array

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I need help with ES6 Promises chaining in array processing.

How to process/define each item of array which goes into `Promise.all` method, when there is other async method inside resolve?

Here is simplified example:

```
function getData(data, callback) {
    let groupPromises = data.map(row => {
        var coordinates = getCoordinates(row);
        return Promise.resolve({
            "place": getPlaces(coordinates), //how to invoke this method
            "data": row
        };
    });     
    Promise.all(groupPromises)
        .then(groups => callback(groups))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

function getPlaces(coordinates) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(coordinates == null) {
            reject();
        }
        parameters = {
            location: [coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude],
            rankby: "distance",
        };
        googlePlaces.searchPlace(parameters, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
            };
            resolve(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this where you add a `.then()` handler to your first promise that gets the `place` and then when that's available returns the object you want. The resolved results of your `Promise.all()` will then be the array of objects you want:

```
function getData(data, callback) {
    let groupPromises = data.map(row => {
        var coordinates = getCoordinates(row);
        // add .then() handler here to convert the place result
        // into the object you want it in
        return getPlaces(coordinates).then(place => {
            return {place: place, data: row};
        });
    });     
    return Promise.all(groupPromises)
        .then(groups => callback(groups))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
    }
}

function getPlaces(coordinates) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(coordinates == null) {
            reject();
        }
        parameters = {
            location: [coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude],
            rankby: "distance",
        };
        googlePlaces.searchPlace(parameters, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
            };
            resolve(response);
        });
    }
}
```

FYI, since you're converting over to promises, why not just return the promise from `getData()` and not use a callback there at all?  Your current code has no way of communicating back an error from `getData()` which is something that comes largely for free with promises.

In fact with pure promises, `getData()` could be simplified to this:

```
function getData(data, callback) {
    return Promise.all(data.map(row => {
        return getPlaces(getCoordinates(row)).then(function(place) {
            return {place: place, data: row};
        });
    }));     
}
```